# React Redux: How to reset the flag between page navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to show the 'Success Message' when a button is clicked in my React-Redux component.

I set the value in the reducer and the message is shown as expected.  The problem is that, if I go to another page (For eg. Home) and come back to /About page, it's still showing that success message and did not go away.

If I go to the /List page, that state has been clear because my reducer is resetting that `resetTodoSuccess` value.  However, it does not make sense for me to reset that value for every routes in my website and I don't think it's the right way to do.

Could you please suggest me what is the best way to set that flag `resetTodoSuccess` to false?

[image]

**AboutPage.js**
I am showing a message when `resetTodoSuccess` is true.

```
export class AboutPage extends Component {
static propTypes = {
    resetTodoSuccess: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    resetTodoItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

onReset = () => this.props.resetTodoItem();

render() {

    const { resetTodoSuccess } = this.props;

    return (
        <Container>
            {
                resetTodoSuccess &&
                <Message message="The items are reset successfully." messageType={MessageType.Success} />
            }
            <Button color="success" onClick={this.onReset}>Reset Todo Items</Button>
            <p className="text-danger">Click here to reset the items of todo.  Please becareful that you will lose any added items.</p>                
        </Container>
    )
}
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
    {   
        resetTodoSuccess: state.todo.resetTodoSuccess
    }
)

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        resetTodoItem: () => dispatch(resetTodoItem())
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AboutPage)
```

**TodoReducer.js**

```
const todoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_TODO_ITEM_SUCCESS: {
            return { ...state, addTodoSuccess: true };
        }
        case actionTypes.LOAD_TODO_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, tasks: action.payload, addTodoSuccess: false, removeTodoSuccess: false, resetTodoSuccess: false };
        case actionTypes.REMOVE_TODO_SUCCESS: {            
            return { ...state, tasks: action.payload, removeTodoSuccess: true };            
        }        
        case actionTypes.RESET_TODO_SUCCESS: {            
            return { ...state, resetTodoSuccess: true };
        } 
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

PS. I'm wondering whether it is really correct to use the React-Redux flow for this kind of functionality.  Because this `resetTodoSuccess` state is no longer useful for other components.

In other words, is it allowed to mix React and React-Redux patterns in different components to call the Async Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an action with an appropriate type. Then you need a reducer which sets `resetTodoSuccess` in redux state to false. Next, add a callback to `mapDispatchToProps()` which dispatches the new action. Finally, implement [`componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) to call the callback.

Answer (score 1):

> PS. I'm wondering whether it is really correct to use the React-Redux
>   flow for this kind of functionality. Because this resetTodoSuccess
>   state is no longer useful for other components.

I don't really think you need to use redux just to display an alert. In my opinion from UX perspective it's better to have alert that has timeout/ fades out. Container for your alert should be always placed in the same spot to not confuse users.

Take a look at [snackbars](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/snackbars/) or if you have top navbar you could add alert just bellow it(with sticky position).

Instead of using redux I would use [pubsub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) lib for that.

1. Create pubsub instance
2. Subscribe to your events eg. alerts, modals
3. Pass pubsub instance to global context
4. Use pubsub from context and publish anytime you need

You can even use pubsub inside your redux actions.

Why I would not use redux just to display alerts? More code to write, more time spent maintaining, more error prone(eg. your forgot to dispatch something).

Here is simple example of pubsub implementation:

```
// Shared events
const ALERT = 'alert';

// Bootstrap app
PubSub.subscribe(ALERT, function(message, alertType) { 
  // invoke alert
  // message text, type of alert, display time in ms
  myFancyAlert(message, alertType, 1000)
});

// publish in any other sub route 
PubSub.publish(ALERT, 'hello world!');
```

Comment: I'm learning React-Redux and all tutorials are using Redux for every single click on the page.  So, I'm confused about the design decisions.  I will definitely look into Material-ui later down in my learning journey.